# Using dom php to get data from table html

Tags: php

i have this error:

```
Error Trying to get property of non-object
```

and the code is:

```
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

    $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

   $i=0; 
   foreach ($rows as $row) 
    { 
        /*** get each column by tag name ***/ 
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

        $this->data['Table'][$i] = array(
                           'Attrb1' => $cols->item(0)->nodeValue,
                           'Attrib2' => $cols->item(1)->nodeValue

                                  );
     $i++;

    } 
         }

        return $this->toArray();
    }
```

The line that i have this error is :

```
'Attrib2' => $cols->item(1)->nodeValue
```

the html code is:

```
<table border=1 align="center" cellpadding=5 width="95%">
                                            <!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0//EN">
<html it>
<head>
<meta name="Generator" content="OLS">
</head>
<body>
<td colspan=2 align="center">
<b>
<i>
Attrib1
</i>
</b>
</td>
<td>
<b>
<i>
Attrib2
</i>
</b>
</td>
<td>
<b>
<i>
<tr>
<td>
A000211
</td>
<td nowrap>
Statistic
</td>
</tr>
```

but i don't know if the problem is in the foreach or all get data that i make is one big error or i process the html in a wrong way..so help me please..

Comment: The error suggests that there are not two TDs in that row. - Which can make sense as a quick scan of the HMTL shows some irregularities that might be corrected when loaded. - Please isolate your issue into an example that you create from scratch containing as little data and code as necessary to demonstrate your issue. Also I suggest to create a HTML table model to deal with tables generally so that you can more easily access rows and columns.

Comment: not the TDs are 8 but still if i try to put all i have this error..and i can't change the html.

Comment: a example of row is: <td>
0065207
</td>
<td nowrap>
Telematic
</td>
<td align="center">
18
</td>
<td align="center">
6
</td>
<td align="center">
04/09/2012
</td>
<td align="center">
2011/2012
</td>
<td>
Check
</td>
<td align="center">
2008/2009
</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$dom->loadHTML($result); 
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($errors);
/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
/*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
/*** get all rows from the table ***/ 
$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
/*** loop over the table rows ***/ 
$i=0; 
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    /*** get each column by tag name ***/ 
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    $this->data['List'][$i] = array(
       'name1' => $cols->item(1)->nodeValue,
       'name2' => $cols->item(2)->nodeValue,
       'name3' => $cols->item(3)->nodeValue,
       'name4' => $cols->item(4)->nodeValue,
       'name5' => $cols->item(5)->nodeValue,
       'name6' => $cols->item(6)->nodeValue,
       'name7' => $cols->item(7)->nodeValue
    );
    $i++;
}
```